# What is the Vue equivalent to Angular's "::" one-time binding?

Tags: vuejs2

I saw that [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) are a possibility but not only is it overly verbose and clunky to achieve the desired functionality, it'd be super convenient to have a ["::"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) equivalent that is written in the view/template code.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>I am a dynamic/observed binding: {{ integerCounter }}</div>
    <div>I am a one-time binding: {{ ::integerCounter }}</div>
    <button @click="integerCounter += 1">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the above snippet, assuming integerCounter is instantiated at 0, the one-time binding will display "0" even if the button is clicked. The dynamic one will update on render.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve exactly? Some example code would go a long way towards getting a suitable answer to your question

Comment: @Phil I'm trying to achieve a one-time binding in Vue template code. I will add example code per your advice, thank you.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by one-time binding in this sense. Could you please make sure your example illustrates the desired behaviour (or at least shows what you don't want to happen)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent example illustrating what you're after but I'm afraid Vue doesn't have anything like this that I'm aware of.

The general advice would be to use two explicit data properties. One could even be [a prop which initialises the local copy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

```html
<template>
  <div>I am a dynamic/observed binding: {{ counter }}</div>
  <div>I am a one-time binding: {{ initialCounter }}</div>
  <button @click="counter++">Increment</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    initialCounter: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data: ({ initialCounter }) => ({
    counter: initialCounter
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: I might take a stab at converting your above pattern into a `<one-time-bind />` component.